# Can I deduct repaid healthcare marketplace subsidy 3 years later

Tags: united-states, taxes, deduction, premiums, subsidy

In 2018 I was enrolled in the marketplace and received a subsidy. I made some withdrawals from an IRA that made me ineligible for the subsidy and owed the entire $8700 back. I didn't have it and went on a payment plan. I just sold my house and paid the entire balance due. Can I deduct the $8700 as health insurance premiums from my 2021 taxes?

Comment: I doubt it. You might be able to correct the 2018 return, but even then you can only deduct them if they're over a certain percentage of your income. I'd be consulting a CPA for this scenario.